# Translating a text about Moldavia from 1597

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Could someone translate this text from 1597?

I am not sure the text is correct, because of the automatic recognition and some manual fixes:

> *Moldavia autem à quibusdam major, Nigra, sive superior VValachia
> dicitur. Nomen autem sortita dicitur à Romano quodam Legato, seu
> Præfecto, Flacco nomine, à quo Flaccia dičta,unde postea exigua
> mutatione VValaccianomen factu est.
>
> Italica quoque lingua olim usi sunt, sed eamita corruperunt, ut natus
> Italus VValachum vix intellecturus sit.
>
> Fuit autem VValachia olim Ungaris tributaria, semper tamen suum
> proprium principem, sive VVayvvodam habuit.*

[image]

The Google translation seem inexact to me

"Moldavia, however, of some to the greater, the black, whether it is above VValachia is said to be. A certain Roman, however, it has chosen is called of the name of the ambassador, or the prefect, the name of Flaccus, whom shall I be Flacco has been said, and that later on only a small change of the VValaccianomen managed.
The Italian language also have been used long ago, but eamita have destroyed it, so that it is born, an Italian VValachum scarcely have understood them.
There was, however, VValachia a tribute in the past they may be anointed, yet he is always the leader of his own, whether it be VVayvvodam for that year."

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the text from?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=9Z_fZA-HszUC&pg=PP72#v=onepage&f=false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a couple fixes to the transcription:

> Moldavia autem à quibusdam major, Nigra, sive superior **W**alachia dicitur. Nomen autem sortita dicitur à Romano quodam Legato, seu Præfecto, Flacco nomine, à quo Flaccia di**c**ta, unde postea exigua mutatione **W**alacci**æ** nomen factu**m** est.
>
> Italica quoque lingua olim usi sunt, sed ea**m i**ta corruperunt, ut natus Italus **W**alachum vix intellecturus sit. Fuit autem **W**alachia olim Ungaris tributaria, semper tamen suum proprium principem, sive **W**ay**w**odam habuit.

My translation:

> Some people call Moldavia "greater", "black", or "upper" Wallachia. This name is said to have come about because of a certain Roman Legate, or maybe Prefect, by the name of Flaccus; it was named "Flaccia" after him, and from that, after a slight change, the name "Walaccia" was created.
>
> They also use the Italian (Latin?) language there, but they've mutilated it so badly that that a native Italian can scarcely understand a Wallachian. At one point, Wallachia was a vassal of Hungary, but it always had its own native ruler, or "Voivode".

Comment: Rather "that a native Italian can scarcely understand a Wallachian", I think.

Comment: @TKR Fixed, thanks!

Comment: tanks a lot @Draconis, I put the source of the book in the first comment. Curious about Moldavia? )

Comment: So, "Italian mutilated", but they don't name it... I just searched references about the language of Moldova, over the eternal dispute how to name it, "moldovan" or "romanian", so here we are )

Comment: @Serge I'm not sure where exactly this text was written, but I'm guessing the writer's native language was something Western Romance (e.g. Spanish). Romanian and (some varieties of) Italian are both Eastern Romance, so they have features in common that all the Western Romance languages lack, and those similarities would stand out more to a Western Romance speaker than to an actual Italian or Wallachian.

Comment: the author is "Levin Hulsius (Nuremberg) typis Christophori Lochneri" https://books.google.com/books?id=9Z_fZA-HszUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: is just the dispute, Moldovans says the language name is Moldovan, and there are multiple sources naming it like this, the Romanians say Moldovan is a dialect... The Moldovans say Walahian is a dialect of Moldovan... )

Comment: and just, if we are here, in order to not open a new question, could you confirm this phrase "Ex hoc autem incluso exemplo responsionis **moldavice**, quam dedit domino capitaneo exercitus cum aliis dominis, qui cum eo erant, vra." is about an answer in **moldovan language**, or is a "moldovan answer", meaning, from Moldova? from here https://scontent-cdg2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/110247415_322626492458325_2884033905847353180_n.png?_nc_cat=108&_nc_sid=8024bb&_nc_ohc=bMlfGkqiTjgAX-h4nAF&_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.xx&oh=4e42998284c7d91893445811d5fb8656&oe=5F393D44

Comment: @Serge I would honestly recommend asking it as a new question; comments aren't long-lived here and it's more useful to have questions others can search for. Feel free to ask it though. I can give a good answer once you do.

Comment: you smart, building the community of QA ))